# How can I create key-value pairs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have used `groupByKey` on my key-value pairs. Now I have this (key, Iterable).
I want to make these key-value pairs from it: ((key,(one element of list)),1) for all list v.

How can I do this? How can loop on iterable list?

```
val lines = sc.textFile("followers.txt").map(s => {
  val substrings = s.split(" ")
  (substrings(0), substrings(1))
})
val aggrigateNeighbors = lines.groupByKey().collect().foreach(println)
val friends = aggrigateNeighbors.flatMap{x=>((k,v.hasNext()),1)}
```

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far.

Comment: Edit your question to include your code. Also explain in what way that code does not do what you want.

Comment: I did. i dont know how can access to my iterable list that is produced by goroupByKey operation.

Comment: v.hasNext returns a boolean not the next element. Also, aggigateNeighbours is no longer a RDD (since you called collect). Assuming you have lots of data, it isn't going to fit.

Comment: So how can I access to iterable list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there.

You need to map over the iterator and make your desired entry from each

Untested, sorry, I'm not in front of the computer on which I could test it.

```
val lines = sc.textFile("followers.txt").map(s => {
  val substrings = s.split(" ")
  (substrings(0), substrings(1))
})
val aggregateNeighbors = lines.groupByKey()
val friends = aggregateNeighbors.flatMap{case (k,v) => v.map{s=>((k,s), 1)}}
```

Comment: I have some errors: value map is not a member of any ! and this: not found value aggrigetneighbors

Comment: Note I corrected the spelling of `aggrigetneighbors `. Looks like you didn't use the code exactly as I posted it?

Comment: I still can't test it, but I just checked it compiles OK, so I think you made a copy and paste error.

Comment: yes, you are right,i wrote s => ((k,s),1) as you tell me

Comment: yes it work, thank you, can I ask another question ?

Comment: If it's not related to this one, post it as another question, and others are more likely to see it too.